# Prove that span($V\W_1$)=$V$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Suppose $V$ is a finite dimensional vector space over $R$ .If $W_1$,$W_2$,$W_3$ are subspaces of $V$ then if $W_1\neq V$,then span($V\W_1$)=$V$

The way I choose to think of this problem is this :
consider a basis for $W_1$. Say {${v_1,v_2...v_k}$}. We can extend this basis for $W_1$ to a basis for $V$. say the basis after extension is {${v_1,v_2...v_k,...,v_n}$}.
Now, we choose an invertible matrix $A$ of order n with no zero entry in $R$.No, I claim that rows of $Av$ where v=$$
    \begin{matrix}
    v_1 \\
    v_2  \\
    v_3\\
.\\.\\.\\v_n\\    \end{matrix}
$$

1.does not belong to $W_1$.
2.form the basis for $V$.

i th row of $Av = \sum_{i=0}^n a_iv_i$. where $a_i\neq 0$

$\sum_{i=0}^n a_iv_i \notin W_1$ since $v_i \notin W_1$ for all $ i>k$

since $A$ is invertible so rows of $Av$ forms a basis for $V$.

Can someone guide me if I am right.

Comment: $V/W$ usually denotes a quotient space, but under this interpretation the statement $\operatorname{span}(V/W_1) = V$ is nonsensical.  Should that instead be $\operatorname{span}(V \setminus W_1)$ instead, where $V \setminus W$ denotes a [set difference](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SetDifference.html)?

Comment: Also, if $V$ is an arbtirary vector space (not necessarily a subspace of $\Bbb R^n$), then the expression $Av$ has no clear interpretation

Comment: @Omnomnomnom respected sir, I understand I did make a mistake. I always have a hard time using these two symbols / and \. The only purpose of using Av was to use the fact that that given a basis it it's linear combinations gives unique representation of elements and if we could choose l.i scalers for linear combination we could get another set of linearly independent elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\{v_1, \ldots, v_k\}$ be a basis for $W_1$ and $\{v_1, \ldots, v_n\}$ its extension to a basis for $V$. Since $W_1 \ne V$, we have $n > k$. Consider
$$B = \{v_1+v_n, \ldots, v_{k}+v_n, v_{k+1}, \ldots, v_n\}.$$
Clearly $v_{k+1}, \ldots, v_n \notin W_1$. Also, notice that $v_i+v_n \notin W_i$ since otherwise we would get $v_n \in W_1$ which is false. Hence $B \subseteq V \setminus W_1$.

Also, for every $x\in V$ we can write
$$x = \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i v_i = \sum_{i=1}^k \alpha_i(v_i+v_n) + \sum_{i=k+1}^{n-1} \alpha_iv_i + \left(\alpha_n-\sum_{i=1}^k \alpha_i\right)v_n$$
so $\operatorname{span}(V \setminus W_1) =V$.

Comment: Thankyou for the answer Sir. I think I had the same idea in my mind but was not able to express it clearly. I choose the matrix A randomly and you have took that A a specific matrix which is [100...01,010...01,001...01,...,000...01]